# Проблема анимации svg при загрузке данных

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animation, loading

Есть простая анимация в svg формате.
Когда начинается загрузка данных анимация останавливается.
В чем может быть проблема?
Ссылка на кодепен:

````
```
````

https://codepen.io/tarasgrynik/pen/eYZabXY

````
```
````

Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

1. Желательно для кнопки задавать type="button"
2. Тормозит оно поскольку вы вбрасываете трудоемкую операцию. (Заменил просто на

```
function LoadData() {
  console.log("ok");
}
```

тормозить перестало. *В примере забыли подключить jQuery

Comment: Тут дело в том что у меня на реальном примере  будут грузиться через ajax данные.
Поэтому операция будет трудоемкой и во время загрузки анимация останавливается.

Comment: Не понятно, почему оно должно тормозиться, в AJAX ведь данные приходят асинхронно... Попробовал пределать вашу функцию через requestAnimationFrame но это не помогло. Возможно следует переделать саму анимацию... stroke-dashoffset возможно тяжелая не оптимизированная анимация. Например заменить те элементы на 3 div а эффект движения задать через opacity / Ну или как вариант вообще эту анимацию забросить в canvas там уже нагрузка должна уйти на GPU пользовательского устройства